# HTML email rendering incorrectly on iPhone 11

Tags: html, css, iphone, html-email, pardot

The company I work for has been using the below email template for a while but the template seems to be displaying incorrectly in iPhone 11 and the 12 Pro Max, but displays correctly for everything else. The background colour doesn't fill the screen.

I'm not a HTML whizz and can't seem to find the problem - any Stack Overflow bosses able to help?

```
`https://pastebin.com/7aARQNMS`
```

Example of how it displays here: [incorrect rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9l5J.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You have only attached the code up to the image - but not the text where the problem is. Please add that in

Comment: @Nathan pastebin link added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing the problem, it should be able to be safely removed (it's also in an iPhone media query too, and in multiple renditions):

```
.email-container {
    min-width: 414px !important;
}
```

Hard to say what that was trying to do, it's quite complex.